# Is Edge by Mobigames 3D or isometric 2D?

Tags: 3d, isometric

I'm trying to make a similar to http://www.cultofmac.com/edge-for-iphone-controversy-rumbles-on-game-again-pulled-from-app-store/13115, but I'm not sure if it's real-time 3D or just really good 2D. Any thoughts?

Comment: What does it matter?

Comment: Erm, because I don't know what would be a good way to start.

Comment: Just pick what you're most comfortable with or what you want to try. If you're using an engine like Unity, it would be silly to do it in 2D though.

Comment: What I meant was part of the process is actually choosing what would be the best method for you, and what you think is best. Both have advantages and inconvenients and the choice just comes down to what you _feel_ better with, like @bummzack said.

Comment: Whatever you do, plase call your game Hedge ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what technology some other game used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a little vague.  Are you specifically asking if Edge uses 2D or 3D graphics?  Or looking for thoughts on whether your similar game should be in 2D or 3D?

Edge certainly looks like it's using full 3D graphics, a fixed camera angle, and orthographic projection.  The fact that a number of game objects rotate leads me to believe that it's all 3D cubes that can be transformed in various ways.  Rather than going through the process of animating a sprite for the necessary cube rotations, 3D graphics would look smoother with less overhead, in my opinion.  However, one could very easily make a similar style of game in isometric 2D.

If you're asking how you should do it, what does your past experience point to?  Do you have more 2D or 3D work experience and do you want to branch out into what you don't know as well?  What engine(s) are you considering?  I think, all things being equal, a simple 2D version of that style of game would be quicker to set up than a 3D one.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the thing that adds most to isometric games is the 2D graphics. You are trying to simulate a 3D enviroment with 2D graphics, so it will take some workaround to get the 3D effect you desire (depth sorting, rotating the view). The game you showed doesn't use any 2D assets. So 3D seems like a more logical choice.

Answer (score 1):

There is one big difference between 2d isometric and 3d games. isometric games always have some **specific** camera and object angles.

If you are going to create a game similar to that one, I guess you can use a isometric view since the games feels complete even without rotating the camera, and it's obvious that object in the game also can only be rendered with some specific angles.

in general you can choose both isometric or 3d game, but 3d rendering consumes much more computational power and may cause low fps in handheld devices like iphone. in the other hand managing game scene in a 3d game is much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

They made a 3D version with perspective some time ago:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mobigame.edge.extended&hl=de

So the rendering in the orthographic (isometric) version is made with 2D-techniques and I think the rotating blocks are just many sprites.